# Stripe + Plaid | Is it possible to have more than one bank account (ach) in sandbox associated to one user?

Tags: api, stripe-payments, plaid

In sandbox mode the UI of plaid with user "user_good" always returns me the same bank account ended with last 4 "6789" of stripe and i need to test in my app a user with two bank accounts, the default and another one.

Is there a way to add more than 1 test bank account in stripe and returned it based on the custom plaid user or other way for an email to have more than one bank account associated via api?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to establish multiple bank accounts for a Stripe customer with Plaid while in test mode. As you mentioned, in test mode the integration will always return the same account (regardless of what is selected in the UI).

If the second account doesn't need to be created via Plaid, then you can [create a bank account token](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_bank_account) using Stripe's [ACH test numbers](https://stripe.com/docs/ach#testing-ach) to use with your testing.

Comment: The link you sent only contains a single success bank account number that matches what you get if you integrate with plaid. Is there no way to get a second successful bank account authorization? It seems a little bizarre to me they would just explicitly disallow testing user flows that involve authorizing multiple bank accounts